# How do i move a 2D object with angle and speed variables in unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, physics

I want to move an object with a certain angle and speed, is there a was to set this as an initial velocity so that it is still possible for the object to collide and bounce of other objects using its rigid body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, here is the code that i made:

```
float angle, speed;
Vector2 newVelocity;

//use sin and cos to work out x and y speed
velocity.x = Mathf.Cos(angle) / speed;
velocity.y = Mathf.Sin(angle) / speed;

//apply the new velocity to the current object
this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = newVelocity;
```